# US visa appointment

Tags: visas, usa, interview, iraq

I am a British Citizen. I visited Iraq few days ago. I understand that I need a visa for the US now. I have applied for the visa but the interview appointments are for September 2024. Would they open up slots for interviews in May or June or that is a false hope? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm sure there are interview slots in May, June, July & August. It's just that they're all booked. You might get on a wait-list to be called in earlier, but you might have to be prepared to come in on 24 hours notice or less. I don't know if they'll actually do that or not, but if so, it's probably your best chance.

Comment: London has very long waiting times (though shorter than Paris). But other embassies or consulates nearby have a lot shorter waiting times, some less than a month, some counted in days. As far as I understand it, contrary to other countries, the US don’t care where you apply. Check https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/global-visa-wait-times.html and book your train (Brussels) or flight (Athens). Still, probably better ri have a good resin to justify going out of your way to get the visa quicker.

Comment: @jcaron my understanding is that the US would look at things such as ties to the UK, which is best done when applying for a visa at the home country (unless that is absolutely not possible) - am I wrong there?

Comment: @Leaderboard most countries apply this logic and only allow you to apply at the consulate or embassy which serves your place of permanent residence. I believe the US don’t care and you can apply anywhere. But as I wrote, probably still a good idea to have a good justification to apply elsewhere.